# Scrolling on Panel instead DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, scroll, scrollbar, panel

I would like to insert my datagridview into a panel with scrollbars. What I have done is setting AutoScroll on the panel to true, make the datagridview fill the panel and disable the scrollbars on it but the scrollbars are not showing on the panel when datagridview have many elements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the `DataGridView` `Dock.Fill` the `Panel`, make it as large as you need to display all `Rows`and all `Columns`!

You need to determine the full `Size` needed to display all `Columns` and all `Rows` without `Scrollbars`:

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) width += col.Width;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) height += row.Height;
dataGridView1.Size = new Size(width,height);
```